# acess the type of input in dojo

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

i enter dojo.query('input') i get the following :-

```
 <input id="paragraphtwo" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/SimpleTextarea" rows="4" cols="50" style="width:auto">
```

now WHEN i write

```
text= dojo.query('input')
 [<input id="paragraphtwo" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/SimpleTextarea" rows="4" cols="50" style="width:auto">]
```

gets storeed in text.

now when i write text[0].id i get "paragraphtwo". how can i access the type of input i.e hwo can i get  "dijit/form/SimpleTextarea" just like i got the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to this is as follows:

```
    var input = dojo.byId("paragraphtwo");
    var dojoType = dojo.attr(input, "data-dojo-type"));​
    console.log(dojoType); // Outputs: dijit/form/SimpleTextarea
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `declaredClass` property:

```
console.log(dijit.byId("paragraphtwo").declaredClass);
```